# Question Asked time should be displayed instead of modified time

Tags: discussion, feature-request

In stack overflow, when I visit https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting it is showing set of questions related to the tags I opted for. However, it is showing the questions which are very old but modified just now OR few minutes ago.

There is nothing to answer these questions as they are answered and few of them are already accepted by the person who asked the question.

It would be better if the questions display is based on the question creation time instead of modification time unless the question is unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may always go to the [Unanswered tab](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered) to see questions which do not have an accepted answer. For questions with no answers you may [go here](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers).

Comment: Even in unanswered it is showing the questions based on votes. Is there a option available to combine mytags and newest in unanswered tab?

Comment: I guess you would have to use the search feature. Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=infavorites%3amine

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the search feature.

Comment: You are welcome. I would like to mention that `infavorites:mine` searches in those posts which you have favorited earlier. So you may have to search for particular tags such as `[java] AND [mysql]`, `[java] OR [android]`, etc.